# Можно ли сделать в Rider поиск подобный Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, rider

Пытаюсь пересесть с Visual Studio на Rider, но многое хочется сделать максимально похожим на Visul Studio.

В VS если я ввожу в поисковую строку, которая расположена в обозревателей решения, то в ней начинают отображаться только те файлы, которые удволитворяют условию поиска.

Если я тоже самое делаю в Rider, то появляются стрелочки вверх и вниз, с помощью которых я могу скакать по совпадения и в окне не остаются только те файлы, которые подходят под условие.

Можно ли это поведение как-то поменять?

Comment: Если поиск по именам модулей нужен, жмете shift два раза, вводите название. Сверху еще вкладку можно выбрать, что именно вам нужно найти.